# Rails 5.0.0 stopped rendering erb code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rendering, erb

I recently tried to update rails '4.2.6' to '5.0.0', and apparently it was successfully done. Needed to run bundle update and bundle install for it.

But when I accessed some html.erb, all code stopped working. Everything that used to execute and display something now displays only:

```
<% code here %>
```

If I downgrade to '4.2.6', everything works.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.